# realm database query to find all objects with a string property contained in a list of strings

Tags: android, realm

using realm for kotlin in android `'io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.4.0'`.
I have the following class:

```
class MyClazz : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var title: String = ""
    var ids: RealmList<Int> = realmListOf()
}
```

I want to find all objects with a `title` contained in this list `listOf("title1", "title5", "title7")`using the `Realm Query Language`. [docs here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/)
I remember it was easy in older versions of realm e.g. using `beginGroup` and `endGroup`, but how to do it now with the `Realm Query Language` ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to do an IN query where you want to see if the left hand expression `title` is in the right hand list `"title1", "title5", "title7"`. If that's correct, use the `IN` as shown in the [comparison operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/#comparison-operators). An example `"progressMinutes IN { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 }"`. If that's not what's being asked, can you clarify?

Comment: thanks, this is correct, if you wish to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do an IN query where you want to see if the left hand expression title is in the right hand list "title1", "title5", "title7".

If that's correct, use the IN as shown in the [comparison operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/#comparison-operators). An example

```
progressMinutes IN { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 }
```